# Android ConstraintLayout: Controls in ImageView mess up ImageView layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to have two, side-by-side ImageViews that spread to take up 50% of the screen each. Over each, I want to arrange an array of Buttons and TextViews. I am doing this in a single `ConstraintLayout`.

When I set up the ImageViews by themselves, they lay out properly using these properties:

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:layout_weight="1"
```

The ImageViews have constraints like this (there's also a **`1dp`** View separator bar):

```
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/separator_bar"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
```

Here's what the split looks like:

[image: The split looks fine]

However, when I add the `Buttons` and TextViews and chain them together, linking them to the sides of the ImageView and each other, making them essentially "contained" in the ImageView, the ImageView shrinks horizontally so that it is the width of the widgets, almost as if wrap_content were applied. What's even weirder is that the other ImageView also shrinks, even though I haven't added its widgets yet.

When marked up, the controls look like this:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnKingW"
    android:layout_width="42dp"
    android:layout_height="42dp"
    android:text="♔"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/btnQueenW"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/tvKingW"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/white_king_image"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/white_king_image"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread" />
```

(the constraints of the original `ImageView` are unchanged)

Here's what it looks like with just one ImageView anchored to the parent on all four sides. The widgets look fine.

[image]

And here's the hot mess when I use the two ImageViews.

[image]

What's going on here? Why does linking a `widget` inside another `widget/view` cause the nice layout that I had before to change? I would assume that the ImageViews were anchored to the parent and shouldn't move, but this is clearly not the case.

I've looked at a bunch of tutorials, but they all seem to show me how to perform a half dozen tricks using the Android Studio GUI and don't really get into the zen of how the layouts are evaluated. I want to actually grok what's going on and not just click some buttons in a GUI design tool. FWIW, I did try the GUI design tool and spent about as much time cleaning up the magic trash it added to my XML (no, I don't need padding, thanks) as I would have saved using the tool, so I essentially abandoned it and now just use it to experiment.

I'm new to Android development, if that isn't clear. This is a toy app for an ungraded Udacity course.

Full XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.android.chessmaniac.MainActivity"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/white_king_image"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:alpha="0.3"
    android:contentDescription="@string/white_king_chesspiece"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@mipmap/white_king"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/separator_bar"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/separator_bar"
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/black_king_image"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/white_king_image"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/black_king_image"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:alpha="0.3"
    android:contentDescription="@string/black_king_chesspiece"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@mipmap/black_king"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/separator_bar"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<!-- WHITE BUTTONS -->

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnKingW"
    android:layout_width="42dp"
    android:layout_height="42dp"
    android:text="♔"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/btnQueenW"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/tvKingW"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/white_king_image"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/white_king_image"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnQueenW"
    android:layout_width="42dp"
    android:layout_height="42dp"
    android:text="♕"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/btnRookW"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/tvQueenW"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/white_king_image"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/btnKingW" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnRookW"
    android:layout_width="42dp"
    android:layout_height="42dp"
    android:text="♖"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/btnBishopW"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/tvRookW"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/white_king_image"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/btnQueenW" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnBishopW"
    android:layout_width="42dp"
    android:layout_height="42dp"
    android:text="♗"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/btnKnightW"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/tvBishopW"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/white_king_image"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/btnRookW" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnKnightW"
    android:layout_width="42dp"
    android:layout_height="42dp"
    android:text="♘"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/btnPawnW"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/tvKnightW"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/white_king_image"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/btnBishopW" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnPawnW"
    android:layout_width="42dp"
    android:layout_height="42dp"
    android:text="♙"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/white_king_image"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/tvPawnW"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/white_king_image"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/btnKnightW" />

<!-- WHITE TEXTVIEWS -->

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvKingW"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="WK"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/tvQueenW"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/white_king_image"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/btnKingW"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/white_king_image"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvQueenW"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="WQ"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/tvRookW"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/white_king_image"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/btnQueenW"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tvKingW" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvRookW"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="WR"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/tvBishopW"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/white_king_image"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/btnRookW"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tvQueenW" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvBishopW"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:text="WB"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/tvKnightW"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/white_king_image"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/btnBishopW"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tvRookW" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvKnightW"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="WN"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/tvPawnW"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/white_king_image"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/btnKnightW"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tvBishopW" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvPawnW"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="WP"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/white_king_image"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/white_king_image"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/btnPawnW"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tvKnightW" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: I think if we could see your entire xml it will be easier for us to help. :)

Comment: Full XML added!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageOne"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/imageTwo"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.65"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageTwo"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@color/colorAccent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/imageOne"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/button2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/guideline" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/guideline"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="232dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/button2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/button2" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="87dp" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**OUTPUT**

[Here is the good tutorial for this](https://medium.com/@loutry/guide-to-constraintlayout-407cd87bc013)

[image]

Comment: Can you explain what you are doing here and why it works? I want to understand what's going on, not just cut-n-paste some code that maybe solves my problem.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to arrange the image views correctly. Like the `LinearLayout`, you can set weight in `ConstraintLayout`.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageOne"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/img_one"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/imageTwo"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageTwo"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/img_two"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/imageOne"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Then try to align button over the `ImageViews`. Hope it helps:)

Comment: I can get the ImageViews to line up using weights and such (see the pic). My problem is that when I add the widgets on top of an ImageView, the ImageView layout gets compressed horizontally.